# Remove .0 from a string in python

Tags: python-3.x, replace, decimal-point

I'm reading a file called MissingItems.txt, the contents of which is a lsit of bar codes and looks like this

```
[3000000.0, 5000000.0, 6000000.0, 7000000.0, 8000000.0, 1234567.0, 1234568.0, 9876543.0, 3000001.0, 5000001.0, 6000001.0, 7000001.0, 8000001.0, 1234561.0, 1234561.0, 9876541.0, 6000002.0, 7000002.0, 8000002.0, 1234562.0, 1234562.0, 9876542.0,9876543.0,9876544.0]
```

I have replaced the square brackets and then split the line as below

```
OpenFile = open(r"G:MissingItems.txt","r")


for line in OpenFile:
    remove = line.replace('[','')
    remove1 = remove.replace(']','')
    plates = remove1.split(",")
    Plate1 = plates[0]
    Plate2 = plates[1]
    Plate3 = plates[2]
    Plate4 = plates[3]
    Plate5 = plates[4]
    Plate6 = plates[5]
    Plate7 = plates[6]
    Plate8 = plates[7]
    Plate9 = plates[8]
    Plate10 = plates[9]
    Plate11 = plates[10]
    Plate12 = plates[11]
    Plate13 = plates[12]
    Plate14 = plates[13]
    Plate15 = plates[14]
    Plate16 = plates[15]
    Plate17 = plates[16]
    Plate18 = plates[17]
    Plate19 = plates[18]
    Plate20 = plates[19]
    Plate21 = plates[20]
    Plate22 = plates[21]
    Plate23 = plates[22]
    Plate24 = plates[23]
```

Is there a way to remove the .0 from the bar codes, preferable before splitting? So I would get '3000000', rather than '3000000.0'. I've tried to use replace, but I'm not sure how to get it to recognize they are at the end of the bar codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using `ast.literal_eval` and `int`.

**Ex:**

```
import ast
with open(r"G:MissingItems.txt","r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        plates = [int(i) for i in ast.literal_eval(line.strip())]
        print(plates)
        # --> [3000000, 5000000, 6000000, 7000000, 8000000, 1234567, 1234568, 9876543, 3000001, 5000001, 6000001, 7000001, 8000001, 1234561, 1234561, 9876541, 6000002, 7000002, 8000002, 1234562, 1234562, 9876542, 9876543, 9876544]
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your file seems to have JSON formatted lines, so you could use a JSON parser:

```
import json
with open(r"G:MissingItems.txt","r") as openfile:
    for line in openfile:
        plate = json.loads(line)
        print(plate)
```

This makes `plate` a list of numbers (not strings), so the difference between 3000.0 and 3000 disappears (as they are representations of the same number). It is only when you would need to output them in a decimal representation that you would worry about the number of decimals to output.

Secondly, it is bad practice to create separate variables for `plate1` `plate2`, ... In such a scenario you should work with a list, and access the values with `plate[0]`, `plate[1]`, ...